# Node.js/Express 4 - How to update a page to show progress in workflow

Tags: html, node.js, express, workflow

i built a small page to track a workflow with multiple steps. The page contains a form with submit button to start the flow. Each step sends back a status to the page. The page html is rerendered with res.render() then and sent to the server with res.send(html).

My problem now  is, that when i use res.send(), the next status update gives a failure, because the response process is finished before.

Using res.write() instead crashes the page for whatever reason. I looks like the page is appended a second time (from a buffer??), instead of overwriting it.

Any ideas how to solve that??

Moe

Comment: You don't need to call res.send after res.render because res.render call it automatically for you

Comment: I am using this way of working `// if a callback is specified, the rendered HTML string has to be sent explicitly
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
  res.send(html);
});` it is also in the official docs this way.

Comment: Without seeing at least some of your code it's difficult to help

Comment: Code ist to long for posting it here. Any idea? Send directly??

Comment: I didn't mean the entire app only the code relevant to the route so others can also have a look at it. But if it's too much to do then send it to suprmen@tiscali.cz